# Valid date formats for synchronizing unpublish dates

Tags: 10, feeds

I'm using Feeds to synchronize content. One of the fields I'm trying to sync is the node's unpublish date (we use Scheduler). I've configured the field as a Blank source because I need to manipulate the information before sending it.

I've tried different date formats, including 'Y-m-d \H:i:s,' 'Y-m-d T\H:i:s,' and 'timestamp.' However, I keep encountering the following error:

> unpublish_on.0.value: This value should be a valid number.
> unpublish_on.0.value: This value should be of the correct primitive type.

This is my tamper:

```php
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function tamper($data, TamperableItemInterface $item = NULL) {

    $fechas_celebracion = $item->getSource()['_fechascelebracion'];

    if (count($fechas_celebracion) === 0) {
      return NULL;
    }

    $date = new \DateTime(end($fechas_celebracion));
    $date->modify('+23 hours');
    $date->modify('+59 minutes');
    $date->modify('+59 seconds');

    return $date->getTimestamp();
    // Return $date->format('Y-m-d \H:i:s');.
  }
```

Interestingly, when I use the following code snippet, it works perfectly:

```php
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$node = Node::create([
  'type' => 'news',
  'title' => 'Druplicon test',
  'unpublish_on' => 1729855491,
]);
$node->save();
```